# Using href to pass argument in HTML

Tags: html, href

I can use the following line in html to pass a static value with a link

```
<button class="light" id = "pg1" onclick="window.location.href = '1.html?theme=light';">page 1</button>
```

Here I have appended `?theme=light` so I can later retrieve the value of `theme` in `1.html`

**My question:** Is there a way for me to send the class variable itself?

*i.e,* if `class="dark"` is there a way I can send theme as `?theme=dark` without changing the parameter myself?

Comment: is there a reason why you can't do it wiht javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must read the class of the current object using a JS function (you're already using JavaScript in the onClick event):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setLink(obj){
    window.location.href = '1.html?theme=' + obj.className;
  }
</script>

<button class="light" id = "pg1" onclick="setLink(this);">page 1</button>
```